# Make a User Role in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I created applications in Oracle Apex, I want 2 types of user to be me. The first is the Admin (I can watch and edit), the second is the User (only watch). But I can’t find instructions anywhere - how can I do this? I created 2 roles in Application Access Control (Admin and User). My authentication scheme in the Authentication Scheme looks:

```
function ischecked (
   p_username IN VARCHAR2,
   p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
r SEC_USERS_LIST%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
select * into r  from SEC_USERS_LIST where upper(LOGIN) = upper(p_username);
   RETURN p_password = r.password;
END;
```

Comment: Please, at the very least, hash your passwords https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: As Scott mentions below, you need to separate the concerns of Authorization from Authentication. Your code sample is purely for Authentication (you'd probably be better off using APEX's built-in authentication) but your question is really about Authorization.

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you usually use 2 different authorization schemes. 
Example:

1. Add a role column to your users table

   ```
   alter table SEC_USERS_LIST add role (number default 10);
   ```

   For example, 10 = normal User, 20 = admin
2. Use a global variable to save a userid.

   Extend your authentication function in a way that it saves the primary key of your user. You will need it later.
   Like this:

   ```
   function ischecked (
      p_username IN VARCHAR2,
      p_password IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BOOLEAN IS
   r SEC_USERS_LIST%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
   select * into r  from SEC_USERS_LIST where upper(LOGIN) = upper(p_username);
      :G_USERID := r.user_id; 
      RETURN p_password = r.password;
   END;
   ```
3. Use two different authorization functions to determine whether someone is an admin or merely a normal user

   [image]

   The autorization function for a normal user `isUser` looks similar:

   ```
   select 1
   from SEC_USERS_LIST
   where user_id = :G_USERID
   and role >= 10
   ```
4. Use your authorization functions

   You can now use your authorization functions wherever you like. If you put `isAdmin` on a navigation menu link or a page region item, a normal user won't see it. If you put `isAdmin` as a page authorization and a normal user will try to access it, he will receive an access denied message. If you put `isAdmin` on a process or dynamic action, then it won't get executed for a normal user.

The other authorization function `isUser` can get used as a application authorization schema at the `Security Attributes`. In this way, only people with at least one of these roles would be able to access your application.

Comment: I'd like to emphasise here the difference between Authentication, and Authorisation. The first lets the user into the applicaiton, the latter controls what the user does once inside.

Comment: Because you need to identify your user in your authorization functions in order to check his/her privileges. There are several methods to do that, saving a user id as a global variable is one of them.

Comment: ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "G_USERID" in application "107". this is errore  I look

Comment: I did it, as you said. But do not work, I have 2 users with columns: USER_ID LOGIN, PASSWORD, RULE
1-values(1,LOGIN, PASSWORD,20)
1-values(2,LOGIN, PASSWORD,10)

Comment: Thomas Tschernich help me?

Comment: Well you need to define the application variable `G_USERID`. You can do that in your shared components in the top left corner, at `Application Items`

Comment: I have another question, how did you add the number of values to the ROLE breaker, from user creation ??? I have a form where Login, password and checkbox with roles! I want the user to be assigned the correct number (10, 20) after choosing a role. Is it real to do?

Comment: I do not understand your questions - and this is getting too broad. You seem to be lacking basic understanding of authorization and authentication concepts. I suggest you to try out the packaged sample applications, the built in access control features mentioned in Koens answer or a tutorial like http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2017/08/create-custom-authentication-and.html

Answer (score 0):

What version of apex are you on ? If you are on a recent version (I believe from 18.1 onwards), then you can use the built-in "access control" feature. This will create 3 authorization schemes for you (Administrator, Contributor, Reader) and the necessary screens to assign users to roles. It only takes minutes to implement and the functionality is enough for most implementations.

- For a new application: check "Access Control" in the application
  wizard (that screen with all the options and the "Create Application"
  button). This will create 3 authorization schemes for you
  (Administrator, Contributor, Reader).
- For an existing application: Create new page, check "Feature" as page
  type, select "access control". I do suggest you do this in a copy of
  your app and not your "master" app so you can play around with it a
  bit and see what the different options do.

Comment: It suits me, but I can't understand where the password is created ?? I'm creating a new rights user, but I don't enter my password!

Comment: You are confusing 2 things: authorization and authentication. Authentication is how a user gets access to the application. Authorization is what funcationility a user has in an application. Those 2 are different concepts, you should not mix them. I suggest you read through the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/establishing-user-identity-through-authentication.html and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/providing-security-through-authorization.html

Comment: .. continued... But I understand your confusion. In most companies, user management is done through some centralized authentication system, like single sign on. So the application doesn't need to know the users exist since they authenticate elsewhere. If you use a home brewn authentication scheme then you need your own infrastructure to create users. In the authorization code users are not created, just assigned to roles.